# Unable to parse browser locale date string to date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, calendar, momentjs

I am using the react day picker, in that I have a string date in locale format.
But I want to return the original date to the server, so I want to parse the string to the Date format.

eg: If the language selected in my browser is ENGLISH(UK) the format is "MM/DD/YYYY" and for ENGLISH(US) it returns "DD/MM/YYYY"
So when I write the new Date(date in locale format) it returns the date by parsing it using the "MM/DD/YYYY" format always

I can parse the date using moment(date, format). But the browser language returned to me in case of navigator.language is "en" for both cases in Chrome browser. So I cannot get the exact format from the list of formats

For English(US): date: 01/05/2019
expected output: 1st May 2019
actual output: 5th Jan 2019

Can someone please share the way to parse a string with different browser locale  to correct date format

Comment: `If the language selected in my browser is ENGLISH(UK) the format is "MM/DD/YYYY" and for ENGLISH(US) it returns "DD/MM/YYYY"` other way around ... `For English(US): date: 01/05/2019` that is 5th Jan 2019 in the unarted states of uhmerica

Comment: Configure the react day picker to always give you UTC time format instead of local time. When working with dates, it's way easier to have all the data in UTC format and then casting it to local time when you need to render, than the opposite, since JS and other languages can natively parse UTC datetime strings, but locale strings need their own parsing function. So my advice would be to turn the logic around. Instead of parsing the date to UTC to send to the server, use UTC everywhere in the app and server and edit the render function to use .toLocaleString().

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to provide locale specific input formatting for your users. Find out the locale used by most of your users, config the datepicker to use that, and maybe you can also set the format string as a placeholder, just for better UX.

Comment: You will save yourself and your users much confusion if you use unambiguous date formats rather than relying on the browser language to guess the format the user expects.

Comment: @Shilly—UTC is not a format, it's a time standard. Perhaps you  mean ISO 8601 format. ECMAScript supports only a very small subset of ISO date formats and a couple of its own, so it would be better to talk of ECMAScript standard formats.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I mean ISO 8601 notation, but got tired of explaining to people what ISO stands for and how it relates to their datetime strings. `YYYYMMDDThhmmssZ`, without `-` and `:`, is not supported. That year, week and ordinal formats are not supported seems irrelevant to me when talking about datetime strings and only seems to further confuse whoever I try to explain things to. So yes, you are 100% correct, but in the spirit of communication, I try to use words I think the listener will understand the best. In the end we both give the same advice.

Comment: @RobG 
I have to display the date in the browser language format only. In the DayPickerInput the format that is displayed is in string and needs to get parsed to Date with the browser's language . Can I achieve that?

Comment: @ShubhamAwasthi—no, not with the built–in parser (which is really rubbish, despite recent updates). The problem with timestamps is that there are so many different formats, some of which are ambiguous. Even without that, to cover all possible formats without any hints would lead to an insanely complicated set of rules.